# create tab menu

Tags: wxpython

**How to create tab menu in wxpython??**

Comment: what is a "tab menu"? Do you mean notebook tabs, or a menu-like thing with tabs such as the Windows ribbon? Or do you mean something else entirely?

Comment: yes,i mean notebook tabs

Answer (score 1):

Check out the wxPython demo (which can be downloaded from the [wxPython download page](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php)).  In the demo, there's an example of how to do a notebook, and a whole section on similar "book" examples.

There's also a [simple notebook example in the wiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Simple%20wx.Notebook%20Example).